# How to limit gems to be installed on different rails environment?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, setup-deployment, capistrano3

I have this in my Gemfile:

```
....
..
# Use Capistrano for deployment
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '3.0.1'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1'
end
```

Now, if I go on my production server and do `RAILS_ENV=production bin/bundle install` it installs the capistrano gem as well. Which makes no sense to me, why would I need capistrano on a production server? So, in my understanding I do not find any use of `group :development` block in Gemfile for bundler. Is there anything I am doing wrong?  How do I make sure that I do not install gems which are not required on production/staging but on local(development/test)? Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong here?

## EDIT

Please note that I know we can use `if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'` for gems which are not required for other environments. What I am looking for is the use of `group` in **Gemfile** for bundler.

Comment: `bundle install --without='production'`

Comment: That's correct. But, `bundle install --without='development'` will install gems from test group? won't it?

Comment: I thought so. Thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to install only gems for production you can use this command:

```
bundle install --without development test
```

or for Heroku:

```
$ heroku config:add BUNDLE_WITHOUT="test development" --app app_name
```

This excludes the development and test environment. If you defined more groups you can add them at the end of this command.

Comment: Yup! Thanks this works!! Much appreciated. I wish had read this: http://bundler.io/v1.5/groups.html, too.